# Are flexbox children "positioned" such that they can be used to absolutely position their children?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, absolute

I am creating a header for my site, which contains a heading, list of navigation links and a search form. The entire page is set out using flexbox, thus:

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="pagecontainer"> <!--the flex container-->
    <header id="pageheader"><!--the header--><h1>...</h1><!--the heading-->
       <nav><ul>...</ul></nav><!--the navigation-->
       <form>...</form><!--the search--></header>
    <main id="pagemain>...</main><!--the main content area-->
    <footer id="pagemain>...</footer><!--the footer-->
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #pagecontainer {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    min-height:100VH;
 }
 #pageheader {
    position:sticky;
    top:0PX;
    ...
 }
 #pagemain {
    flex:1;
    ...
 }
 #pagefooter {
    ...
 }
 #pageheader form {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    ...
 }
```

The problem I am experiencing is that in Firefox, the search field is correctly positioned--at the bottom-right of the header--but in Chrome (and in other Webkit browsers) it is at the bottom-right of the page.
According to the MDN article on position, (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), absolutely positioned elements are
   "positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor. If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used."
So obviously Firefox sees the flex-positioned elements as being positioned, but Webkit sees them as being in the normal flow. Which behaviour is "correct"? and is there some fallback I can use instead?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if Chrome's behavior is correct, but Firefox's is definitely coded to an older version of the spec (and the spec text on absolute positioning inside of a flexbox has changed several times).

Bug on updating firefox behavior: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=874718

In the meantime, I'd recommend against relying on Firefox's current behavior regarding absolutely-positioned things inside of a flex container (unless they've got a `position:relative` ancestor between them and the container -- see below).

Answering your other questions:

- No, flex items are not considered "positioned" (and do not become abspos containing blocks for their descendants).
- It's easy to make them behave like that, though -- just style them with `position:relative`.

Comment: Thanks, Dholbert. Does position:sticky count as being positioned? I would have thought it does, as it is (partially) fixed, but in saying that, those elements are in the document flow as well. And a stupid question, but it would be semantically incorrect to set position:sticky and position:relative or position:sticky relative or some such, wouldn't it?

Comment: "Does position:sticky count as being positioned" - yes, in that the sticky thing should become an abspos containing-block (just as a position:relative thing would do).  And you're right that you cannot make something *both* relative *and* sticky-positioned.  You could probably achieve something like that with nesting, though. (sticky-positioned wrapper, relatively-positioned child, or something similar)

Comment: Thanks, Dolbert. I have accepted your answer since, with your comment, it fully answers my question. In this case, from what i can gather, Firefox's behaviour is correct, as the header is possitioned sticky.

Comment: Just a fiddle to visualize firefox bug with absolute positioning inside flex container. The yellow box must hide the first pink box. http://jsfiddle.net/homyasusina/yxfzczmr/1/